# mysql separating tables

Tags: php, mysql, migration

i made a mistake and i have to split 1 table into 2. i have a product table and i need category table. when i started i only had 1 category per product but not (with new business requirement) i need the ability to put a product in multiple category.

i have a product tables that has a category in it.

here's the table:

```
product (id, name, category, price etc...)
```

now, how can i efficiently migrate this without make my site offline?

i have lamp on centos

Comment: yes varchar(40) not null field since the category is required when inserting product

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First make sure your categories are unique. Make sure you don't have something like:

```
productx and produtx
```

Otherwise, when you will inserts bad categories.

You will have to do it in step:

**1) Creating the table category**

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'General',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Create the intersection table since a product can be in multiple category and a category can have multiple product.

```
CREATE TABLE `product_category` (
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY product_category (`product_id`,`category_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**2) inserts the categories into the table.**

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO category SELECT DISTINCT category from product;
```

This will insert non duplicate categories into the category table with a unique id.

Now, you have to inserts these records in the

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `product_category` SELECT `product`.`id` AS `product_id`, `category`.`id` AS `category_id` FROM `category` LEFT JOIN `product` ON (`category`.`name` = `product`.`category`);
```

**3) Now you have to modify your code in order to use the right query:**
Example:

```
SELECT 
 /* your fields */
FROM
product
INNER JOIN product_category ON (product.id = product_category.product_id)
INNER JOIN category ON (category.id = product_category.category_id)
WHERE ...
```

**4) Now, when you feel comfortable with your code changes, you can drop the unused column:**

```
ALTER TABLE product DROP COLUMN category;
```

Comment: thanks i had 3 categories with similar name and for putting queries all together, you help is appreciated

Comment: you are very welcome, let me know if you need additional help

Comment: question: your query you put will that be used for when i want to select my products? or categories? or both? and why unique key on the category?

Comment: 1) unique category name because i doubt you want duplicate category name (kinda what i said with productx and produtx in my answser)

Comment: 2) that is an example, if you want only categories you just get the records from the category table, if you want product, only the product table if you need both, then you have to use this query

Answer (score 3):

Create a table category:

```
CREATE TABLE category(id int primary key not null auto_increment, category varchar(40))
```

Then select unique categories from product table:

```
INSERT INTO category (category) SELECT DISTINCT category FROM product;
```

Then create a table for relations:

```
CREATE TABLE product_to_category (product_id int, category_id int);
```

If you want, you can use foreign keys and constraints.

Then you can migrate your existing relations:

```
INSERT INTO product_to_category SELECT product.id, category.id FROM product JOIN category on category.category=product.category;
```

After that, adjust your code to use the new structure and drop the category column from product table:

```
ALTER TABLE product DROP COLUMN category;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO new_table_name ("product", "category")
SELECT id, category
FROM product;
```

Then add a foriegn key constraint on id in new_table_name which references the original product table. After this you can `alter table product drop column column_name`.

Comment: MySQL Server doesn't support the SELECT ... INTO TABLE Sybase SQL extension. Instead, MySQL Server supports the INSERT INTO ... SELECT standard SQL syntax, which is basically the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You would start by normalizing your product table - creating 2 new tables:

```
CREATE TABLE categories
(
  cat_id int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  cat_label varchar(40)
);

CREATE TABLE product_by_category
(
  pbc_prod_id int REFERENCES products(id),
  pbc_cat_id int REFERENCES categories(cat_id),
  #indexes for quicker lookup...
  INDEX pbc(pbc_prod_id,pbc_cat_id),
  INDEX cbp(pbc_cat_id, pbc_prod_id)
);



  INSERT INTO categories(cat_label) SELECT DISTINCT category FROM product;
   INSERT INTO product_by_category(pbc_prod_id, pbc_cat_id)
      SELECT id, (SELECT cat_id FROM categories WHERE categories.cat_label = product.category)
      FROM products;

    ALTER TABLE products DROP COLUMNN category;  #do this after you are satisfied with contents of new tables.
```

Then you would have to create joins for getting products by category.

Comment: OOps, it looks like favoretti beat me to this with a similar solution

Comment: Yours is neater as you actually took the time to include proper references and even indexes! :)